# Tail recursive binomial coefficient function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion, binomial-coefficients

I have a function that calculates the binomial coefficient in Haskell, it looks like this:

```
binom :: Int -> Int -> Int
binom n 0 = 1
binom 0 k = 0
binom n k = binom (n-1) (k-1) * n `div` k
```

Is it possible to modify it and make it tail recursive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There is a standard trick of using [an accumulator to achieve tail recursion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Accumulating_parameter). In your case, you'll need two of them (or accumulate one rational number):

```
binom :: Int -> Int -> Int
binom = loop 1 1
  where
    loop rn rd _ 0 = rn `div` rd
    loop _  _  0 _ = 0
    loop rn rd n k = loop (rn * n) (rd * k) (n-1) (k-1)
```

**Update:** For large binomial coefficients, better use `Integer` as `Int` can easily overflow. Moreover in the above simple implementation both numerator and denominator can grow much larger than the final result. One simple solution is to accumulate `Rational`, another would be to divide both by their [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) at every step (which AFAIK `Rational` does behind the scenes).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, if you introduce a helper function that takes an extra parameter:

```
-- calculate factor*(n choose k)
binom_and_multiply factor n 0 = factor
binom_and_multiply factor 0 k = 0
binom_and_multiply factor n k = binom (n-1) (k-1) (factor * n `div` k)

binom n k = binom_and_multiply 1 n k
```

The last line could be rewritten in point-free style:

```
binom = binom_and_multiply 1
```

---

EDIT: The function above shows the idea, but is actually broken, because the `div` operand truncates and opposed to the original version, there is no mathematical proof that the value to divide always is a multiple of the denominator. So that function must be replaced by the suggestion by Petr Pudlák:

```
-- calculate (n choose k) * num `div` denom
binom_and_multiply num denom _ 0 = num `div` denom
binom_and_multiply _   _     0 _ = 0
binom_and_multiply num denom n k = binom_and_multiply num denom (num * n) (denom * k) (n-1) (k-1)

binom = binom_and_multiply 1 1
```

---

In non-optimizing haskell implementations, you might be disappointed that the "properly tail recursive" variant still gobbles up lots of memory if you choose high values for `n` and `k`, because you are trading stack space in the non tail-recursive implementation by heap-space, as haskell is too lazy to calculate all the products just in time. It waits until you really need the value (maybe to print it), and just stores a representation of the two product expressions on the heap. To avoid that, you should make `binom_and_multiply` as they say *strict in the first and second parameter*, so the product will be eagerly evaluated while doing the tail recursion. For example, one could compare `num` and `denom` to zero, which will need to evaluate the expression for factor before going on:

```
-- calculate (n choose k) * num `div` denom
binom_and_multiply 0 0 _ _ = undefined  -- can't happen, div by zero
-- remaining expressions go here.
```

The general way to make sure the product is not "evalutated to large" is using the `seq` function:

```
-- calculate (n choose k) * num `div` denom
binom_and_multiply num denom _ 0 = num `div` denom
binom_and_multiply _   _     0 _ = 0
binom_and_multiply num denom n k = 
      new_num = num*n
      new_denom = denom*k
    in new_num `seq` new_denom `seq` binom_and_multiply new_num new_denom (n-1) (k-1)
```

This tells the haskell implementation that the recursive call to `binom_and_multiply` may only occur after `new_num` and `new_denom` has been evaluted (to WHNF, but explaining WHNF is out-of-scope for this question).

One last remark: What this answer was doing is called generally *transforming a right-fold into a left-fold* and then *making the left-fold strict*.

Answer (score 1):

An "automatic" way to make a function tail recursive is to rewrite it using [continuation passing style](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) (which is by definition tail recursive).
Arguably a straightforward way to do it in Haskell is to convert the original function into monadic form and then use [Cont monad](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style#The_Cont_monad) to execute the result:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

-- | Original function in monadic form
binomM n 0 = return 1
binomM 0 k = return 0
binomM n k = do
  b1 <- binomM (n-1) (k-1)
  return $! b1 * n `div` k

-- | Tail recursive mode of execution
binom :: Int -> Int -> Int
binom n k = binomM n k `runCont` id
```

Note: This way many monadic functions can be converted into tail recursive ones simply by adding [ContT transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#g:3) to their monadic stack.